# How to set a JSON string in HTTP POST request header in Ionic 2?

Tags: http, post, ionic2

I was trying to set a JSON object to the header of a POST request in Ionic 2.

```
var data= {attr1:"value1", attr2:"value2", attr3:"value3"};
headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');
headers.set('data', JSON.stringify(data));
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
```

But I get `data:    {"attr1":"value1"` in the request. The entire string gets split by comma.

Not only a JSON string, if I try to set any string with a comma, the characters after comma do not appear in the request. For example:

```
headers = new Headers();
headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');
headers.set('data', 'abc,def');
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
```

I will get `data:    abc` in the request.

How to set a JSON string(or any string with a comma) in the header of a request in Ionic 2?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you can try putting your JSON string inside this link and see whether is it valid? https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Instead of                                                                                              `headers.set('data', JSON.stringify(data));`                                                                try                                                                                                                                  `headers.append('data', JSON.stringify(data))`

Answer (score 0):

You can Escape Character \  before the comma, so that compiler can ignore comma and put the string intact.

eg:  `headers.set('data', 'abc\,def');`